# Function on AJAX success or location.reload to reload info?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function in an include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Customers', 'Status'],
      ['Accepted',     <?php echo $rowsaccepted ;?>],
      ['Declined',      <?php echo $rowsdeclined;?>],
      ['Not Reviewed',  <?php echo $rowsnreview;?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
                   'width':200,
                   'height':200,
                   'backgroundColor':'#474747',
                   'legend': 'none',
                   'chartArea':{left:20,top:0,width:250,height:250},
                   colors: ['#ef8200', '#007fc2', '#41cf0f'],
                   fontSize:14,

               };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

}   


</script>
```

As you can see it accepts three PHP variables that are defined by a query to a MySQL table in another include. The function works as needed and the chart represents the data well, but only when the page loads or is reloaded (as expected).

I have the following AJAX that triggers the query that updates variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".accept").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var order_id = element.attr("data-order");

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   data: {id:del_id,order_id:order_id},
   success: function(){}
});
  $(this).parents("#show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
  .animate({ opacity: 0.25 }, "slow");
});
});
</script>
```

Id like to execute the function when the AJAX call succeeds. Do I just add it to the success section as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   data: {id:del_id,order_id:order_id},
   success: function drawChart
});
```

I must have something wrong because the AJAX call no longer functions when the function is added to success. Is this the best way or would a simple location.reload at the end of the AJAX be problematic?

Thanks

Comment: The ajax call sends data to server on my browser...

Comment: Where are you seeing that in chrome? I dont have anything in my network tab and the function isnt running as required.

Comment: Using Firefox... Request is fired. You might want to add `console.log()` in `drawChart` too, or add a breakpoint there

Comment: Im going to edit my post slightly and ask this in a different way - thanks for your help